# Rails 3.1: Asset pipeline with named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

**Rails 3.1.0.rc5**

I am having trouble getting named routes to work within an ERB-enabled Javascript file:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/items.js.erb
$('#start').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url : '<%= ajax_items_path %>',
    success : function(result) {
      $('#result').html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Error compiling asset items.js:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `ajax_items_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fbcb49a7630>:0x007fbcb4ee30b8>
  (in myproject/app/assets/javascripts/items.js.erb)
```

The `ajax_items_path` route works fine if I use it directly in a view.

It looks like named routes aren't available within the Asset Pipeline. If this is the case, what is the workaround? I really want to avoid hard-coding URLs in my Javascript.

Comment: A workaround would be to return the URL in the HTML, e.g. as a data-attribute on #start, and extract it from there.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem in Rails 3.1.0
Did you find any solution ?
thanks

Comment: Thibault: Yes, tristanm's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A workaround is to use your route helpers from `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`, e.g.

```
<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.ajax_items_path %>
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me this ```a[href="/d/users/sign_in"]```